# Maven Malformed POM (invalid token)

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Windows 7, maven 3.0.5 and java 1.7.0_71
When building this specific project with

```
mvn clean install -U -DskipTests -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

or

```
mvn clean install -U -DskipTests
```

I get this error message:

```
FATAL: IOError: Malformed POM '.../effective-pom.xml': <unknown>:43:20: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

the line where this error happens is

```
<name>xxxx xxxx</name>
```

Strangely this happens only on my machine, not on others, so it might be a encoding problem.
But I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Try adding something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: that did it. It's still surprising that I'm the only one with this problem though everyone in my team is using the pom.xml file without this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to your `pom.xml`.

> that did it. It's still surprising that I'm the only one with this problem though everyone in my team is using the pom.xml file without this tag.

Check the encoding settings on your maschine. Something must be different.

Comment: after short research, I realized, that windows **should** use UTF-8, but for some reason in my case it doesn't. Also it seems rather difficult to change the encoding to UTF-8: [http://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7](http://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be, to set the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
But in my personal opinion, using `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is far better, because it is not dependent on the enviroment variable, which may vary from system to system